# How do I select multiple elements from a list?

Tags: python, list, random

With this code I'm able to select one comment from `comments.txt` and comment it without repeating itself. How do I select multiple comments at the same time from the `comments.txt` without the comments repeating themselves?

```py
def random_comment():
    num = randint(1, COMMAND_AMOUNT)
    while num in USED:
        num = randint(1, COMMAND_AMOUNT)
    USED.append(num)
    return COMMENTS[num]    

USED = []
file = open("comments.txt", "r")
COMMENTS = {num: comment.strip() for num, comment in enumerate(file.readlines(), start=1)}
file.close()

COMMAND_AMOUNT = len(COMMENTS)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could call `random_comment()` multiple times.

Comment: Using random will possibly give you repeats.  Instead do a random shuffle of the list and pick comments in order from the shuffled list.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
SAMPLE_SIZE = 4 # for example (your question does not indicate how many element should be selected)

def random_comments():
    return random.sample(COMMENTS, SAMPLE_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure there are no repeats:

```python
import random

with open("comments", "r") as f:
    COMMENTS = [comment.strip() for comment in f]
random.shuffle(COMMENTS)

def random_comment():
    return COMMENTS.pop() if COMMENTS else None

# print all the comments until no more:
for comment in iter(random_comment, None):
    print(comment)
```